# What is the difference between referencing a field by class and calling a field by object?

Tags: java, object, reference, field

I have noticed that there are times when coding in Java that I have seen fields called by method:

```
System.out.println(object.field);
```

and by class:

```
System.out.println(Class.field);
```

I have not seen any clear distinguishing in my textbooks about what the semantics are for these two cases, and I fear that it is going to be, at least for a noob, a subtle point. My intuition is that the class calling will be used for static fields?  Thanks guys. So much con'foo'sion.

Comment: You're asking two different questions. In your title your asking about calling by object and in content you're asking about calling by method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `Class.field` can be accessed without creating an instance of the class. These are `static` fields which are initialized when the classes are loaded by classloaders.

The other field i.e. `object.field` can be accessed only when an instance of the class is created. These are `instance` field initialized when object of the class is created by calling its constructor.

Answer (score 3):

`object.field` should be (see note below) an instance member while `Class.field` would be a static member.

*Note: Like stated by @radai and I think it's worth mentionning, you can also access a static member through an object instance, however that's a very bad practice which is quite misleading.*

Comment: technically you can reference a static field from an actual instance too, not just from a class, but its a horrible practice.

Answer (score 1):

Instance scope versus class scope.

Check this out:

```
class Foobar {
  public final int x = 5;
  public static final int y = 6;
}
```

`y` is a variable that is only created once, at compile time. It is bound to the class, and therefore shared by all of its instances. You reference this with `Foobar.y`.

```
System.err.println(Foobar.y);
```

`x` on the other hand, is an instance variable, and every `Foobar` that you create with `new` will have a copy of it. You would reference it like this:

```
Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
System.err.println(foobar.x);
```

But this will not work:

```
System.err.println(Foobar.x);
```

Answer (score 1):

> My intuition is that the class calling will be used for static fields

Yes `SomeClass.field` can be used only if `field` is `static`. In this case you can also  access it via reference like `someClassRef.field` but this code will be changed by compiler to `ReferenceType.field` anyway. Also it can cause some misunderstandings (it may seem that you are trying to use non-static field) so it is better to use static fields by its class.

If `field` is not static then it must belong to some instance so you will have to call it via reference `someClassRef.field`

Answer (score 1):

Refrencing a field by class requires the field to be static.

Refrencing a field by object requires the field can be either static or non-static field .